# Creating an object using a string

Tags: java, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use string in place of variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157539/use-string-in-place-of-variable-name)

Is there any way in Java that allows an object to be created using a string?

Let's say, i have a class called "Toyata", is there anyway i can create an object of Toyata 
using the string variable s in class Car?

```
public class Car{
String s = "Toyota";
}

public class Toyota{
int speed;

public Toyota(int speed){
this.speed=speed;
}

}
```

Comment: No, you really don't want to do this with Java. Trust me. If you want to associate a String with another object, use a `Map<String, OtherType>`. This question should be closed as it has been asked and answered thousands of times before. Please Google this and you'll see.

Comment: Doing this is a huge sign of code smell.  _Find another way._

Comment: From the OOP point of view, Toyota *is* a Car, therefore `public class Toyota implements Car`. If there's any generic implementation, you may want to extend `GenericCar` class: `public class Toyota extends GenericCar`, where `public class GenericCar implements Car`. Not really answer to your question, but it may be you are on the wrong track here.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use reflection, but you need a fully qualified classname:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030634/1217408

EDIT:

Hovercraft Full Of Eels's comment about using a `map` lookup is probably far more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: But you shouldn't do this as there are far better ways of associating a String with a reference type object.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Agreed, so I added your alternative and recommended it. It's the reason _can_ is italicized, since it is what the askee wants, but hopefully the better alternative will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query for class (assuming it's in the default package this should work) via the value of `s`. Then you have to lookup the proper constructor via your class' `getConstructor()` method.  Since `Toyota` does not contain a default constructor, you need to query for one that matches your expected parameters. In this case, it's an `int`.  `int` is represented in `Class` form by `Integer.TYPE`. Finally after that is all said and done, you can call `newInstance()` on the constructor with the desired speed passed in and you should have a new instance ready to use. Of course there will be a few checked exceptions to handle.

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(s);
Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor(new Class[] {Integer.TYPE});
Toyota toyota = (Toyota) constructor.newInstance(new Object[] {90});
```